# How do I cycle through elements in a div and get all of their ids?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='divID'>

<ul id="gallery">

    <li id='123'>
    <h5>Stephen</h5>
    </li>

    <li id='444'>
    <h5>Daniel</h5>
    </li>

</ul>

<button id='savebutton' type="button">Save</button>

</div>
```

So I want to find the ids '123' and '444' when I press the button.

I've tried the following, but it's only giving me the id of the div, instead of the elements in the div (so it just returns 'divID'):

```
$( "#savebutton" ).click(function() {
  $('#divID').each(
  function(){
     var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(currentId);
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since those are the `li` elements under the ul with id `gallery` use that as the selector. `#gallery`([id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector)) for selecting `ul` and [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)(`li`) for selecting `li`s inside it

```
$("#savebutton").click(function () {
    $('#gallery li').each(function () {
        var currentId = this.id;
        alert(currentId);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9mFFV/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#divID li')` to get all child list items